# Can you make a node title \ heading link to it's NID?

Tags: theming

I'm looking for a way to click a node's title to refresh it's very page. For example, if the current node is node/1 and I'll click it's **title \ H1** the page will be refreshed...

Tried to go to > structure > Content types (desired content type) > edit > edit display, but I couldn't find an option to edit the Page-heading \ h1 there.

I must say I'm looking for a **non-modular** solution (preferably without customization also).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are possibly few ways to do this.

Not sure if this actually works, but I *think* it does, you can install [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) and go to Manage Display tab and apply one of display suite's layouts to your "Full" view mode. After you do that, Display Suite will give you all the fields (including Title) on the Manage Display tab of that view mode. From there you just need to configure the fields and config the "title" field and check the option "Link title to node".

You could also do it from template files, I guess it qualifies as non-modular? For example in `node.tpl.php` or `page.tpl.php` (wherever the page_title is being printed) one can easily create a link to the current node if the `$node` object is available or if not the node ID's available from the URL always. From there it should be a pretty easy call to `l()`:

```
<h1 class='page_title'><?php print l($page_title, 'node/'.$node->nid); ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The page titles are not hyperlinks as you have discovered. Clicking the browser's refresh button allows you to refresh the page.

So perhaps you could say more about what problem you are trying to solve or function you are trying to add here. You can add new fields to the cont type and make such fields hyperlinks. But it's difficult to imagine a case where one needs to be able to hyperlink the title of the page itself.

In short, the answer is "no you can't do that" out of the box.

Comment: Of course clicking the refresh button or f5 will refresh the page - but it's sometimes more comfortable to refresh the page via hyperlink h1, when the mouse is on it (or very close to it); It might also saves some time (in accumulation) when happens with lot's of editors checking small changes in a changed page.